# Show charts inside my modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, chart-web-part, powerbi

I want to build 3 charts and show them inside my SharePoint online modern page, the charts are as follow:

[image]

1. First chart is to group the items from a single SharePoint list by Created date, and show the total number of items based on the day of the week (Mon till Sun).
2. Second chart is to show the total number of items from 4 different lists and show the percentage inside a pie chart
3. Third chart is to group the items from a single SharePoint list by Created date, and show the total number of items based on the month from the first month of the year till current month.

So, how I can build such charts and show them inside modern SharePoint page?

Can I use the modern Quick charts web part, Power App or Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

Quick chart web part in SharePoint can only show the simple data without allowing any grouping/calculation (for data as well as labels).

So, you cannot achieve your above requirements using Quick chart web part.

**Possible solutions**:

1. Power BI:

   - Using Power BI, you can quickly create reports using simple as well as complex calculations
   - You can embed Power BI report on modern page using [Power BI web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-power-bi-web-part-32d8b85f-094d-4152-8e3b-df641ccf3968)
   - You will need Power BI licenses to share the reports with other users.
2. SPFx web part:

   - You can achieve your requirements by developing custom SPFx web part.
   - You can use [ChartControl control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ChartControl/) to fasten your SPFx development.
   - No additional licenses or cost but requires more time for development.

   See few SPFx samples developed by community members at:

   1. [Chart Control Samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-chartcontrol)
   2. [Modern Charts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-modern-charts)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. PowerBI  sound like a valid approach.. but do you know if the reports described inside my question can be achieved in PowerBI? thanks

Comment: Yes, these reports can be easily achieved using Power BI.

Comment: so in PowerBI, i can achieve report-1 where i will need to show the total number of items in one week? so if today is Saturday so the report should show the total number of items  from previous Friday till today (Saturday)?  for report-2 i can connect the PowerBI report with 4 SharePoint lists and get their total and build the pie chart? finally for report-3 i can get the total number of items from the first month of the year till the current month? thanks

Comment: Yes, if you have better knowledge of building Power BI reports, it is easily possible I believe. You can connect multiple SharePoint lists & get data, manipulate data as per your needs, even create tables in you report based on list data/calculations & show charts based on those tables in Power BI.

Comment: Please [mark this as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way. It will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.